# pytorch rnn loop over rnncell

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to understand actual implementation of RNN forward , which I expect at some point has to have a loop over time step(sequence) that uses rnn cell.

While checking actual c++ [code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/rnn.cpp#L450) on github at got stuck at this point.
I'm wondering where is the torch::rnn_tanh code?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#Tanh under def forward I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Matt That's tanh that simply applies element wise tanh to input, torch::rnn_tanh signature is very different. it takes in ``` result = torch::rnn_tanh(
          input,
          hx,
          flat_weights_,
          options_base.bias(),
          options_base.num_layers(),
          options_base.dropout(),
          this->is_training(),
          options_base.bidirectional(),
          options_base.batch_first()); ```

Comment: Isn't tanh the default for rnn anyhow? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#RNN

Comment: @Matt torch::rnn_tanh code is a c++ code that take in all network parameters. At some point it probably calls c++ tanh,  but that's not my questions. I'm looking for a c++ source code for rnn_tanh.